# Confusing results from Poisson distribution with Mathematica 11

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, poisson

I used
`P=PDF[PoissonDistribution[m]]`
to create a probability density function of the poisson distribution with mean value "m". Thus, Mathematica defines a function
`P(k)=m^k e^(-m) / (k!)`
for `k` larger than or equal to 0.

This function is the same as the standard discrete Poisson distribution. However, using `P(0)` results in a probability density of 0 at `k=0` which differs from the expected probability density of the standard discrete Poisson distribution, which should be `e^(-m)` at `k=0`.

I have no idea why this happens. Any helpful comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you get a wrong result is simply because you typed P(0) instead of P[0]. In Mathematica, when you want to apply a function to an argument, you must use square brackets.

Comment: I also suggest that you post your questions on Mathematica Stack Exchange, where you can find better support.